# div by iframe over

Tags: javascript

I want put a div by iframe over a video containing an active player

is it possible ?

Comment: not entirly shure what you mean. Is the video Flash, Quicktime, Windows Media Player, etc. And what do you mean by "div by iFrame"

Answer (score 1):

If the video you are talking about is in flash, so long as you set wmode=transparent in the flash embed code, you can place HTML on top of the flash content using css z-index.

Comment: sadly wmode=transparent adversely affects firefox scroll-wheel :( .. it's always something~~

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may want to use `wmode="opaque"`